# IndexError: list index out of range even though the list exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transactions

```
Merchant Coordinates
ISSUES HERE> 

12043
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-3255d6529f5d> in <module>
      4 
      5 print(len(data.merchant_long_lat))
----> 6 data["merchant_long_lat"]=[[coords.split(" ")[1], coords.split(" ")[0]] for coords in data.merchant_long_lat]
      7 data.merchant_long_lat.head()

<ipython-input-74-3255d6529f5d> in <listcomp>(.0)
      4 
      5 print(len(data.merchant_long_lat))
----> 6 data["merchant_long_lat"]=[[coords.split(" ")[1], coords.split(" ")[0]] for coords in data.merchant_long_lat]
      7 data.merchant_long_lat.head()


IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the issue I currently face

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from haversine import haversine, Unit


# In[2]:


data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Intel/Downloads/ANZ.xlsx')
data.head()


# In[3]:


pd.DataFrame({"Column": data.columns})


# In[4]:


print("Data shape", data.shape)


# In[5]:


print("Basic Checks!")


# In[6]:


print("Number of unique customer IDs =",data.customer_id.nunique())


# In[7]:


print("There are ", len(data), "rows in the dataset")
print("Number of unique transaction IDs =",data.transaction_id.nunique())


# In[8]:


data.date.describe()


# In[9]:


pd.date_range(start="2018-08-01", end="2018-08-31").difference(data.date)


# In[10]:


data.info()


# In[11]:


print("Finding missing values!")
missing = data.isnull().sum()
missing = missing[missing > 0]
missing_percentage = round(missing / len(data), 1) * 100
pd.DataFrame({"Number of missing values": missing, "Percentage": missing_percentage}).sort_values(by = "Percentage", ascending = False)
pd.DataFrame({"Number of missing values": missing, "Percentage": missing_percentage}).sort_values(by = "Percentage", ascending = False)


# In[12]:


print("Basic Descriptive Statistics Of Numerical Variables")
data.describe()


# In[13]:


print("Exploratory Data Analysis")
data.status.value_counts(dropna = False)


# In[14]:


data.card_present_flag.value_counts(dropna=False)


# In[15]:


data.currency.value_counts(dropna=False)


# In[16]:


data.long_lat.head()


# In[17]:


data.txn_description.value_counts(dropna=False)


# In[18]:


plt.figure(figsize = (10,5))
sns.countplot(data.txn_description)
plt.title("Number of transactions by category")


# In[19]:


data[["txn_description", "amount"]].groupby("txn_description", as_index = False).mean().sort_values(by="amount", ascending=False)


# In[20]:


plt.figure(figsize = (8, 5))
sns.barplot(x = "txn_description", y = "amount", data = data)
plt.title("Average transaction volume by category")


# In[21]:


data.gender.value_counts(dropna = False)


# In[22]:


print("Mean Amount Spent By Each Gender")
data[["gender", "amount"]].groupby("gender", as_index = False).mean().sort_values(by = "amount", ascending = False)


# In[23]:


plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
sns.countplot(data.gender)
plt.title("Number of transactions by gender")


# In[24]:


print("Average Amount Spent By Each Gender | Visualized")
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
sns.barplot(x="gender", y="amount", data=data)
plt.title("Average Transaction Volume By Gender")


# In[25]:


print("Merchants By Suburb In Descending Order")
data.merchant_suburb.value_counts(dropna=False)


# In[26]:


print("Merchants By State In Descending Order!!!!")
data.merchant_state.value_counts(dropna=False)


# In[27]:


print("Number Of Transactions By Merchant's State | Visualized")
plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
sns.countplot(data.merchant_state)
plt.title("Number of transactions by state")


# In[28]:


print("Getting Merchant State and Amount ")
data[["merchant_state", "amount"]].groupby("merchant_state", as_index=False).mean().sort_values(by="amount", ascending=False)


# In[29]:


print("Average Of Transaction Amount By Merchant's State | Visualized")
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
sns.barplot(x="merchant_state", y="amount", data=data)
plt.title("Average transaction volume by state")


# In[30]:


print("Timestamp For Each Column")
data.extraction.head()


# In[31]:


data[["date", "extraction"]].head()


# In[32]:


print("Country Of Transaction Or Data")
data.country.value_counts(dropna=False)


# In[33]:


print("Merchant Longitude and Latitude")
data.merchant_long_lat.head()


# In[34]:


print("Movement(Cr/Dr)")
data.movement.value_counts(dropna=False)


# In[35]:


print("Number Of Transactions (Based On/By) Movements | Visualized Using Countplot")
sns.countplot(data.movement)
plt.title("Number Of Transactions By Movement")


# In[36]:


plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
sns.barplot(x="movement", y="amount", data=data)
plt.title("Average transaction amount by movement")


# In[ ]:


print("Balance")
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
sns.distplot(data.balance)
plt.title("Balance Distribution")


# In[ ]:


plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
sns.boxplot(data.balance)


# In[ ]:


print("Age Of Customers")
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
sns.distplot(data.age)
plt.title("Age Distribution")


# In[ ]:


print("Amount Spent/Transacted")
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
sns.distplot(data.amount)
plt.title("Amount Distribution")
print("EDA Ends Here...")


# In[ ]:


print("Feature Engineering \n")

print("Dropping Currency & Country as They are The Same And UnWanted Columns")
print("Before: ", data.shape)
data = data.drop(["currency", "country"], axis=1)
print("After: ", data.shape)


# In[ ]:


print("Identifying Missing Values In The Columns")
pd.DataFrame({"Number of missing values": missing, "Percentage": missing_percentage}).sort_values(by="Percentage", ascending=False)


# In[ ]:


print("Eliminating Transactions With No Purchases")
nonSales = data.loc[(data.txn_description != "SALES-POS") | (data.txn_description != "POS"), :]
nonSales.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending = False)


# In[ ]:


print("Filling Missing Values With N/A")
cols = ["card_present_flag", "merchant_state", "merchant_suburb", "merchant_id", "merchant_long_lat"]
for col in cols:
    data[col].fillna("n/a", inplace = True)


# In[ ]:


missing = data.isnull().sum()
missing = missing[missing > 0]
missing.sort_values(ascending = False)


# In[ ]:


data = data.drop(["merchant_code", "bpay_biller_code"], axis=1)


# In[ ]:


data.isnull().sum().max()


# In[ ]:


print("Creating DayOfWeek, Month and Hour Features")
daily_amount = pd.DataFrame(data.groupby("date").amount.sum())
daily_amount.head()


# In[ ]:


fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
ax.plot(daily_amount.index, daily_amount.amount)
plt.title("Transaction Volume From 1/8/2018 to 31/10/2018")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Transaction  Volume")


# In[ ]:


data["month"]=pd.DatetimeIndex(data.date).month
data["dayofweek"]=pd.DatetimeIndex(data.date).dayofweek
data[{"date", "month", "dayofweek"}].head()


# In[ ]:


data.extraction.head()


# In[ ]:


data["extraction"] = [timestamp.split("T")[1].split(".")[0] for timestamp in data.extraction]
data.extraction.head()


# In[ ]:


data["hour"] = [time.split(":")[0] for time in data.extraction]
data[["extraction", "hour"]].head()


# In[ ]:


print("Before: ", data.hour.dtype)
data["hour"]=pd.to_numeric(data.hour)
print("After: ", data.hour.dtype)


# In[ ]:


data.head()


# In[ ]:


print("Purchases And Overall Amount")
purchases_amount = data.loc[(data.txn_description == "POS") | (data.txn_description == "SALES-POS"), "amount"]
purchases_amount.head()


# In[ ]:


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
sns.distplot(purchases_amount)
plt.title("Purchase Transaction Amount")


# In[ ]:


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
sns.distplot(data.amount)
plt.title("Overall Transaction Amount")


# In[ ]:


data.amount.describe()


# In[ ]:


purchases_amount.describe()


# In[ ]:


print("Transaction Volume Per Customer")
customer_monthly_volume=pd.DataFrame(data.groupby("customer_id").amount.sum()/3)
customer_monthly_volume.head()


# In[ ]:


print("Monthly Transaction Volume | Visualized")
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
sns.distplot(customer_monthly_volume.amount)
plt.title("Customers Monthly Transaction Volume")


# In[ ]:


print("Transaction Volume By Month | Visualized")
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
sns.barplot(x="month", y="amount", data=data)
plt.title("Average Transaction Volume By Month")


# In[ ]:


print("Volume Throughout The Week")
average_daily_volume = pd.DataFrame(data.groupby("dayofweek").amount.mean())
average_daily_volume.head()


# In[ ]:


print("Transcation Volume On An Average Day")
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
ax.plot(average_daily_volume.index, average_daily_volume.amount)
plt.title("Average Transaction Volume per Day")
plt.ylabel("Transaction Volume")
plt.xlabel("Day of week")


# In[ ]:


data.txn_description.value_counts()


# In[ ]:


data.loc[data.txn_description == "PAY/SALARY", "category"] = "Salary"
data.loc[(data.txn_description == "SALES-POS") | (data.txn_description == "POS"), "category"] = "Purchase"
data.category.fillna("Others", inplace=True)
data[{"txn_description", "category"}].head(10)


# In[ ]:


stacked_barplot=pd.DataFrame(data.groupby(["dayofweek", "category"]).amount.count())
stacked_barplot.unstack().plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, figsize=(12, 7))
plt.title("Number Of Transactions Each Day By Category")
plt.legend(["Others", "Purchases", "Salaries"])
plt.ylabel("Number of transactions")
plt.xlabel("Day of week")


# In[ ]:


average_hourly_volume = pd.DataFrame(data.groupby("hour").amount.mean())
average_hourly_volume.head()


# In[ ]:


fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
ax.plot(average_hourly_volume.index, average_hourly_volume.amount)
plt.title("Average Transaction Volume per Hour")
plt.ylabel("Transaction Volume")
plt.xlabel("Hour")


# In[ ]:


stacked_barplot=pd.DataFrame(data.groupby(["hour", "category"]).amount.count())
stacked_barplot.unstack().plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, figsize=(12, 7))
plt.title("Number Of Transactions Each Hour By Category")
plt.legend(["Others", "Purchases", "Salaries"])
plt.ylabel("Number of Transactions")
plt.xlabel("Hour")


# In[ ]:


data[["long_lat", "merchant_long_lat"]].head()


# In[ ]:


print("Customer Coordinates")
data["long_lat"]=[[coordinate.split(" ")[1], coordinate.split(" ")[0]] for coordinate in data.long_lat] 
data.long_lat.head()


# In[ ]:


print("Merchant Coordinates")

print("ISSUES HERE> \n")

print(len(data.merchant_long_lat))
data["merchant_long_lat"]=[[coords.split(" ")[1], coords.split(" ")[0]] for coords in data.merchant_long_lat]
data.merchant_long_lat.head()


# In[ ]:


new_df=pd.DataFrame({'MerchantLocation':(tuple(num) for num in data.merchant_long_lat), 'CustomerLocation': (tuple(num) for num in data.long_lat)})

for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
    x=row.CustomerLocation
    y=row.MerchantLocation

    if x[0]!="" or x[1]!="" or y[0]!="" or y[1]!="":
        try:
            new_df["CustomerLocation"] = new_df.CustomerLocation.replace(x, (float(x[0]), float(x[1])))
            new_df["MerchantLocation"] = new_df.MerchantLocation.replace(y, (float(y[0]), float(y[1])))

        except:
            print("one of these should be N/A")
            new_df["CustomerLocation"] = new_df.CustomerLocation.replace(x, (x[0], x[1]))
            new_df["MerchantLocation"] = new_df.MerchantLocation.replace(y[0], y[0].replace('n/a','1'))
            new_df["MerchantLocation"] = new_df.MerchantLocation.replace(y[1], y[1].replace('n/a','1'))

        else:
            print("There is an empty string")
            new_df["MerchantLocation"] = new_df.MerchantLocation.replace(float(y[0]), float(y[0]))
            new_df["MerchantLocation"] = new_df.MerchantLocation.replace(float(y[1]), float(y[1]))
            print(x,y)
            #print(haversine((x[0], x[1]), (y[0], y[1]), unit='mi'), "miles...")

#print(haversine((x[0], x[1]), (y[0], float(y[1])), unit='mi'), "miles")
```

This is my code and the issues are where I have typed "ISSUES HERE". Even though the list exists as evident when running the code with the Forage's Data@ANZ Virtual Internship excel file.

P.S. The second issue is with the string not getting replaced even when it's caught!

Comment: I could bet that `coords.split(" ")` returns at least at one point only a list of length 0, therefor `coords.split(" ")[1]` raises an error.

Comment: Ah... that makes sense. Most of them had a space except a few. Do you think I should drop the empty strings first? Thanks.

Comment: Try `str.strip()`.